# If elements are different, collapse

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I have two columns that I want to collapse if they are different. If they are the same, just keep the value. If there is one `NA`, keep the other one.

```
df
#   element1 element2
#1        A         
#2        B        B
#3        C        D
#4        A     <NA>
```

And I need the following column:

```
#  element1 element2 element12
#1        A                  A
#2        B        B         B
#3        C        D       C,D
#4        A     <NA>         A
```

Any hint on how can I do that?

Data:

```
df = data.frame(element1 = c("A", "B",  "C","A"),
                 element2 = c("", "B","D", NA));df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach with `apply()`:

```
#Code 1
df$Var <- apply(df[1:2],1,function(x) trimws(paste0(unique(x[!is.na(x)]),collapse = ','),
                                             whitespace = ','))
```

Output:

```
  element1 element2 Var
1        A            A
2        B        B   B
3        C        D C,D
4        A     <NA>   A
```

Or the `dplyr` version:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df %>% mutate(across(everything(),~as.character(.))) %>%
  replace(is.na(.),',') %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Var=trimws(paste0(unique(c_across(element1:element2)),
                                              collapse = ','),whitespace = ',')) %>%
  replace(.==',',NA)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Rowwise: 
  element1 element2 Var  
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>
1 A        ""       A    
2 B        "B"      B    
3 C        "D"      C,D  
4 A         NA      A
```

Comment: Good one Duck, concise and fast yet again.

Comment: Duck, I can see without whitespace argument, there's a comma after A in first row. It replaces ',' with a whitespace and then the trimws removes it?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
> df %>% mutate(element3 = case_when(
There were 14 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
+                                   element1 == element2 ~ element1,
+                                   is.na(element1) & !is.na(element2) ~ element2,
+                                   is.na(element2) & !is.na(element1) ~ element1,
+                                   element1 == '' & element2 != '' ~ element2,
+                                   element1 != '' & element2 == '' ~ element1,
+                                   element1 != element2 ~ paste(element1, element2, sep = ',')
+ ))
  element1 element2 element3
1        A                 A
2        B        B        B
3        C        D      C,D
4        A     <NA>        A
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `tidyverse` option.

If you want to get rid of annoying empty strings `""` and make them `NA`, you can use `na_if`.

A `case_when` can concatenate the strings if they are different, with `coalesce` used in case one or other is missing (`NA`).

If neither are the case, then both columns are the same, and just set as first value.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  na_if("") %>%
  mutate(element12 = case_when(
    element1 != element2 ~ paste(element1, element2, sep = ','),
    is.na(element1) | is.na(element2) ~ coalesce(element1, element2),
    TRUE ~ element1))
```

**Output**

```
  element1 element2 element12
1        A     <NA>         A
2        B        B         B
3        C        D       C,D
4        A     <NA>         A
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can do this with `paste` and `sub`

```
df$elements12 <- gsub("(?<=.)(?=.)", ",", sub("(.)\\1+", "\\1", 
     do.call(paste, c(replace(df, is.na(df), ""), sep=""))), perl = TRUE)
```

-output

```
df$element12
#[1] "A"   "B"   "C,D" "A"
```